# Can you get css opacity to stack (especially in IE)?

Tags: html, css, filter, opacity, alpha

Say I have 3 divs, one sitting on top of another.

However, given the following example and the css, it seems like the outer div's transparency always take priority over the inner ones. I tested this out in jsFiddle, and the whole thing is just 50% white. Is there a way to get the transparency to stack? So that in this example, my inner square would have a opacity ~80%?

```
<div class="o1">
    <div class="o2">
        <div class="o3">
            blah
        </div>
        blah
    </div>
    blah
</div>

body {
    background-color: black;
}

.o1 {
    background-color: rgb(255,255,255);
    filter:alpha(opacity=50);
    opacity: 0.5;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}

.o2 {
    background-color: rgb(255,255,255);
    filter:alpha(opacity=50);
    opacity: 0.5;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
}

.o3 {
    background-color: rgb(255,255,255);
    filter:alpha(opacity=50);
    opacity: 0.5;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think u need to use

```
rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
```

instead.

is this what you need? [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ggGKe/8/)

Comment: No (yes, that's what I need but...), I can't use rgba, I already had something working with rgba before, but had to change them because I need stupid IE8 to work, and I also need it to work under "Compatibility Mode" as well.

Comment: As i don't have any way to test it I can't help you a lot but it seems that [this](http://css-tricks.com/rgba-browser-support/) guy found a way to resolve it with IE only css.

Answer (score 0):

Not as children, but as seperate `DIV` absolutely positioned on top of one another:

http://jsfiddle.net/6Wnhy/